# facet ggplot by span argument of loess smoother

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, loess

I would like to make a single facetted plot (lattice style) by varying the span parameter to the loess smoother. I tried using a for loop as below but no plot was produced. If I were to use the ggsave function, the plots are saved separately.

In addition, I was wondering if there is a more parsimonious way to do such a task?

```
x <- rep(1:10,4)
y <- 1.2*x + rnorm(40,0,3)
s <- seq(0.2,0.8,0.1)

# plot the series of plots by varying the span parameter
for (s_i in s) {
    qplot(x, y, geom = 'c('point','smooth'), span = s_i)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach will work just fine if you explicitly `print` the plot (and get rid of your extra `'` mark):

```
for (s_i in s) {
    print(qplot(x, y, geom = c('point','smooth'), span = s_i))
}
```

As for other ways to do it, I would recommend putting all your plots in a list

```
changing_span = list()
for (i in seq_along(s)) {
    changing_span[[i]] <- qplot(x, y, geom = c('point','smooth'), span = s[i]) +
        labs(title = paste("span:", s[i]))
}
```

Then you can plot all of them together with, e.g.,

```
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, changing_span)
```

Comment: You can also simulate facetting by adding a facet strip with the span value to each plot. For example (using `ggplot` instead of `qplot`): `lapply(s, function(span) {
  ggplot(data.frame(dat,span=paste0("Span = ", span)), aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() + geom_smooth(span=span) +
    facet_grid(. ~ span)
})`